# how to use materialApp context in initState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i am using easy_localization package to help me start my app with a certain language. I have a `showDialogue` run in initState. though since one of the language is not the device default language I am getting the following error on run.

> E/flutter ( 6984): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found.

**everything else works but the Dialogue is never pushed:(**

I even tried constructor injection but I cant get it work

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showDialog<String>(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ApproveDialogue(
                child: ChooseLanguageDialogue(),
              ));
    });
  }
```

From What I read it has to do with the context being used is from `main()` not `materialApp`..so I am bit lost how to access that one in initState. or any other fix.

Thanks for the help

Comment: does it work if you abstract the widget? On the app you put `return MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());` and then you make a MyWidget statefulwidget and put the dialog there?

Comment: At which level are we talking here? the widget tree look like this `main(EasyLocalization) --> MaterialApp --> OnBoarding(contains initState for dialogue)` @h8moss they are abstracted